# Unique Name with accompanying date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, t-sql

Hi folks for the following table

```
╔═════╦════════════╗
║ Org ║    Date    ║
╠═════╬════════════╣
║  A  ║ 1/1/2015   ║
║  A  ║ 12/3/2015  ║
║  B  ║ 8/10/2015  ║
║  B  ║ 30/5/2015  ║
║  C  ║ 4/4/2014   ║
║  D  ║ 19/11/2014 ║
╚═════╩════════════╝
```

how do I write a query so that I obtain only one unique org name corresponding to the earliest dates where there are more than one date i.e.

```
╔═════╦════════════╗
║ Org ║    Date    ║
╠═════╬════════════╣
║  A  ║ 1/1/2015   ║
║  B  ║ 30/5/2015  ║
║  C  ║ 4/4/2014   ║
║  D  ║ 19/11/2014 ║
╚═════╩════════════╝
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You got your answer, but as this concept seems to be new for you, here is the explanation: What you want to do here is called aggregation. You condense your data such as to show only one result row per Org. This "per Org" translates to `GROUP BY Org` in SQL. Then for every other column decide what aggregate to show (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, ...). In your case you want to see `MIN(Date)`.

Comment: Tsql with MySQL, that's a very odd combination... Please, remove invalid tags.

Comment: You should really review the answers given below and show us some green.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `MIN` to get the earliest date and `GROUP BY` to obtain only 1 unique org name.

```
    SELECT Org, MIN(Date) AS 'Date' FROM TableName GROUP BY Org
```

Comment: And don't use single quotes for alias names. Single quotes are for string literals. Double quotes are for aliases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , oh sorry i didn't observe that you already have an answer, do you want me to delete mine ?

Comment: No worries...this question is so easy anyone could get it on their own :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql **STR_TO_DATE** or **Group by**

```
Select * from (SELECT * FROM `tbl` order by STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%d/%m/%Y') ASC) as new_tbl group by Org
```

Comment: Don't do this. First of all, what gives you the idea that `Date` is a string? I don't find this likely. Then you group by Org, but also access `Date` (by selecting \*). As you are not using any aggregate function (MIN, MAX, etc.) on it, you get one of the matching Dates per Org. It may be that in *your* MySQL version the DBMS picks the first value from the sorted subquery, but this is in no way guaranteed. Don't rely on this; it's just an implementation detail subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` along with the `MIN` function to obtain the earliest date for each `Org` group:

```
SELECT Org, MIN(Date) AS Date
FROM table
GROUP BY Org
```

Comment: Well, with one basic assumption

Comment: Rather than blasting anti-social comments, why don't you let us know what the assumption is.  And why did you not choose to also comment on the other answers which are similar to this one?

Comment: That the 'dates' are not as described by the OP. 'Blasting'? Really?

Comment: Good point, and it wouldn't surprise me if the `Date` column has a non date-time type.

Comment: Because you know better ;-)